# getting unit test case error?

Tags: apex, unit-test

when I am executing my unit test for the apex class

> "salesforce No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a
>   test method.  Please make sure the iterable returned from your start
>   method matches the batch size, resulting in one executeBatch
>   invocation."

```
    @isTest
public class PWQuartertionconts_Test {

@isTest static void testQuar() {
    Test.StartTest();   
    par_f pf=new par_f();
    pf.name='Test12';
    pf.Current_Units_in_Fund_num=100; 
    pf.Total_Capital_Contributed=66;
    pf.Capital_Redemptions_of_All_Investors=33;
    insert pf;
    system.debug('pf'+pf); 

     Qua_Dis qd=new Qua_Dis();     
     qd.Pref_Dis=1;
     qd.Prof_Dis=1;
     qd.Purchase_Price_Per_Unit=1;
     qd.Quarter='Q1';
     qd.Year='2016';
     qd.par_f=pf.id;
     insert qd;
     system.debug('qd'+qd);

     RecordType rt1 = [Select Id,Name From RecordType Where Name = 'Investor Partner' And SobjectType = 'cont'];
     cont ct=new cont();
     ct.Membership_In='PICR Fund III L.P.';
     ct.LastName='test30';
     ct.RecordTypeId=rt1.Id;
     ct.par_f = pf.Id;
     ct.Units_In_Fund=222;
     ct.cont_Types='PICR Investor';
     ct.Distribution_Type='Distribution';
     ct.cont_Type='Investor';
     /*ct.Investment_Cost_Basis=550;
     ct.Total_Redemptions=112;
     ct.Total_Distributions=639;
     ct.par_f__r.Total_Capital_Contributed=256;
     ct.par_f__r.Capital_Redemptions_of_All_Investors=356;*/
     insert ct;
     system.debug('ct'+ct);

    Prof_Dis prof=new Prof_Dis();
    prof.Investor_Name=ct.Id;
    prof.Status='calculated';
    prof.Qua_Dis_Name=qd.Id;
    prof.Share_Percentage=1;
    prof.Share_Amount=1;
    prof.Quarter=qd.Quarter;
    prof.Year=qd.Year;
    insert prof;
    system.debug('prof'+prof);

    Pref_Dis pref = new Pref_Dis();
    pref.Investor_Name=ct.Id;
    pref.Status='calculated';
    pref.Qua_Dis_Name=qd.Id;
    pref.Share_Percentage=1;
    pref.Share_Amount=1;
    pref.Quarter=qd.Quarter;
    pref.Year=qd.Year;
    insert pref;

    system.debug('pref'+pref);
    Apexpages.StandardController stdController = new Apexpages.StandardController(qd);
    PWQuarterlyDistributionconts cont = new PWQuarterlyDistributionconts(stdController);
    cont.QDD();
Test.StopTest();

}

 public static testMethod void testcapibution() {
  Test.StartTest(); 
    par_f pf2=new par_f();
    pf2.name='test99';
    pf2.Current_Units_in_Fund_num=10; 
    pf2.Total_Capital_Contributed=63;
    pf2.Capital_Redemptions_of_All_Investors=32;
    insert pf2;
    system.debug('pf2'+pf2); 

     Qua_Dis qd2=new Qua_Dis();     
     qd2.Pref_Dis=1;
     qd2.Prof_Dis=1;
     qd2.Purchase_Price_Per_Unit=1;
     qd2.Quarter='Q2';
     qd2.Year='2016';
     qd2.par_f=pf2.id;
     insert qd2;
     system.debug('qd'+qd2);

     RecordType rt2 = [Select Id,Name From RecordType Where Name = 'Investor Partner' And SobjectType = 'cont'];
     cont ct2=new cont();
     ct2.Membership_In='PICR Fund III L.P.';
     ct2.LastName='test30';
     ct2.RecordTypeId=rt2.Id;
     ct2.par_f = pf2.Id;
     ct2.Units_In_Fund=222;
     ct2.cont_Types='PICR Investor';
     ct2.Distribution_Type='Reinvestment';
     ct2.cont_Type='Investor'; 
     insert ct2;

     RecordType rt3 = [Select Id,Name From RecordType Where Name = 'Investor Partner' And SobjectType = 'cont'];
     cont ct3=new cont();
     ct3.Membership_In='PICR Fund III L.P.';
     ct3.LastName='test31';
     ct3.RecordTypeId=rt3.Id;
     ct3.par_f = pf2.Id;
     ct3.Units_In_Fund=222;
     ct3.cont_Types='PICR Investor';
     ct3.Distribution_Type='Distribution';
     ct3.cont_Type='Investor'; 
     insert ct3;

    Prof_Dis prof2=new Prof_Dis();
    prof2.Investor_Name=ct2.Id;
    prof2.Status='calculated';
    prof2.Qua_Dis_Name=qd2.Id;
    prof2.Share_Percentage=1;
    prof2.Share_Amount=1;
    prof2.Quarter=qd2.Quarter;
    prof2.Year=qd2.Year;
     prof2.Distribution_Type=ct2.Distribution_Type;
    insert prof2;
    system.debug('prof2'+prof2);

    Pref_Dis pref = new Pref_Dis();
    pref.Investor_Name=ct2.Id;
    pref.Status='calculated';
    pref.Qua_Dis_Name=qd2.Id;
    pref.Share_Percentage=1;
    pref.Share_Amount=1;
    pref.Quarter=qd2.Quarter;
    pref.Year=qd2.Year;
    pref.DistributionType=ct2.Distribution_Type;
    insert pref;

    Prof_Dis prof3=new Prof_Dis();
    prof3.Investor_Name=ct3.Id;
    prof3.Status='calculated';
    prof3.Qua_Dis_Name=qd2.Id;
    prof3.Share_Percentage=1;
    prof3.Share_Amount=1;
    prof3.Quarter=qd2.Quarter;
    prof3.Year=qd2.Year;
    prof3.Distribution_Type=ct3.Distribution_Type;
    insert prof3;
    system.debug('prof2'+prof2);

    Pref_Dis pref2 = new Pref_Dis();
    pref2.Investor_Name=ct3.Id;
    pref2.Status='calculated';
    pref2.Qua_Dis_Name=qd2.Id;
    pref2.Share_Percentage=1;
    pref2.Share_Amount=1;
    pref2.Quarter=qd2.Quarter;
    pref2.Year=qd2.Year;
    pref2.DistributionType=ct3.Distribution_Type;
    insert pref2;

    RecordType c2 = [Select Id,Name From RecordType Where Name = 'Contribution' And SobjectType = 'Capl_C'];

     Capl_C df= new Capl_C();
     df.RecordTypeId=c2.Id;
     df.Type='Preferred Distribution Reinvestment';
     df.Type='Profit Distribution Reinvestment';
     df.par_f=pf2.Id;       
     df.Contribution_Amount=1000;
        //df.Redemption_Amount=5000;
     df.Investor_cont=prof2.Investor_Name;
     df.Date=Date.newInstance(2016,08,02);
     df.Purchase_Price_Per_Unit=qd2.Purchase_Price_Per_Unit;
     df.Prof_Dis_ID=prof2.Id;
     df.Preffered_Distribution_ID=pref.Id;
     insert df;

     Capl_D cdd=new Capl_D();
     cdd.Investor_cont=prof3.Investor_Name;
     cdd.Quarter=prof3.Quarter;
     cdd.Year=prof3.Year;
     cdd.Prof_Dis_ID=prof3.Id;
     cdd.Distribution_Date=Date.newInstance(2016,08,02);
     cdd.Distribution_Amount=prof3.Share_Amount;
     cdd.Description='Profit Distribution';
     cdd.From_par_f=prof3.Qua_Dis_Name__r.par_f;     
     cdd.Investor_cont=pref2.Investor_Name;
     cdd.Quarter=pref2.Quarter;
     cdd.Year=pref2.Year;
     cdd.Pref_Dis_ID=pref2.Id;
     cdd.Distribution_Date=Date.newInstance(2016,08,02);
     cdd.Distribution_Amount=pref2.Share_Amount;
     cdd.Description='Preferred Distribution';
     cdd.From_par_f=pref2.Qua_Dis_Name__r.par_f;
     insert cdd;
     Apexpages.StandardController stdController2 = new Apexpages.StandardController(qd2);
     PWQuarterlyDistributionconts cont = new PWQuarterlyDistributionconts(stdController2);
     cont.capitaldistribution();
     Test.StopTest();
  }
  }
```

i am getting above error.

Comment: Please include the code that is causing the error and the test class. See - [ask]

Comment: Please, paste here the apex and test class code

Comment: Are you executing another batch in your finish method? If so you will have to use an isrunningtest check. And the above code is not a unit test it is not testing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You may be processing more than 200 records in test class for the batch apex. Try to pass less than 200 records in test class since the Salesforce.com test framework only allows you to test one execute.

Comment: i have attached the unit test

Comment: ok give a sample code to control the records

Comment: @user37822 You need to track down any `Database.executeBatch` calls in your code base and see how they relate to your test case. You may be able to modify your test to not hit the problem, but equally you may have to add a `Test.isRunningTest()` guard code to stop the batchable or limit its size.